# Apache Camel Quartz + File copy

Tags: apache, quartz-scheduler

I am new to the apache-camel. I have a requirement for the project to copy file from one location to another. For this i gone through Camel in action and solved it as:

```
from("{{INPUT_FILE_PATH}}")
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("TESTING========="+exchange.getIn().getBody());


        }
    }).to("{{PROCESSED_FILE_PATH}}");
```

But now i have a requirement to implement quartz with camel. I had gone through some of the articles on the camel site related to quartz but i confused with it. I have a requirement to process file on everyday 5am. I had also tried for delay with input file name but it works when u want to pic up a file after specific interval time. So if any of you guys implemented quartz with camel can u please let me know how could i implement it with the above code.

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below using camel Quartz.
Add camel-quartz dependency in your pom.xml

By default Quartz looks for quartz.properties in the class path, you can also provide the configuration details in the xml as shown below:

```
<bean id="quartz" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent">
    <property name="propertiesFile" value="com/test/app/myquartz.properties"/>
</bean>

Using above bean form your route as below

   <route>
        <from uri="quartz://fileProcessorJob?cron=0+0+1+*+*+?"/>
        <to uri="file:data/inbox?noop=true"/>
        <to uri="file:data/outbox"/>
    </route>
```

Comment: But what if i want to do some processing with the files which i fetched using file:date/inbox. As i am planning to use Bindy to map my CSV files to a Pojo and do some processing for the records. So how do i integrate all these things to gether with annotations / xml. (i.e. Quartz implementation, file:data/inbox fetching, Bindy to  map CSV record to object). Can you give me an example for the same then it would be much helpful.

Comment: Does this work? That first `to` tag tries to write out a null file to the folder in my case.